# Text spacing on latex svg screwed when embedded

Tags: floats, subfloats, svg

I have been trying to import svg images into my latex document, but latex seems to screw up the text spacing. I produce the SVG files using pyplot in python. The images look fine inkscape with proper spacing as defined in python, but latex always seems to "compress" the text boxes. The problem is fixed when using the "embed fonts" option on inkscape pdf export, but then the text is too small to read. Therefore I would like to keep the normal latex font size and only space the text somehow.
First image shows the actual svg in inkscape with proper spacing, the seconds image the SVG embedded in subfloat in latex.

[image: Actual image produced in inkscape]
[image: Image embedded in latex using subfloat]

Latex code:

```
\begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfloat[First.]{\includesvg[scale=0.45]{Combined_Data1.svg}}\qquad
\subfloat[Second.]{\includesvg[scale=0.45]{Combined_Data_nk.svg}}\qquad
\caption{Two sub-floats.}
\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You'll probably also need to provide the SVG files. Additionally, please complete your example. We cannot test the code without adding anything, thus we might add something different than you.

Comment: The svg is exported with inkscape to a format latex can handle. So you need to adjust this export, check the docu of the svg package for the relevant options.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i tried to adjust the spacing manually in inkscape and even if there is more spacing done, latex is shifting it together again. When I use the pretex=\tiny option, the spacing is fine, but the text is too small. And other commands for textspacing like \quad or \hspace are not working as I thought for adding space between the texts.

Comment: note latex isn't doing anything here the includevg package is using inkskcape to generate  latex text + a pdf image , if that is wrong it will look wrong in latex and latex can do nothing about that, so the important thing is what latex was generated. we can't see the original svg or the generated latex so it is hard to comment

Answer (score 0):

The spacing is the same in both versions, it's just that, as you noted, the text is much smaller with the embedded font making the offset between the text lines appear larger (relative to the text size). But the offset is in fact identical.

You will probably want to adapt the Python script creating the image. The best option is to set the image dimensions and text size to the values you actually use in your document and then include them without the `scale` option. You can of course also just shift the axis labels..